# Best practice on how to store geography

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio-lightswitch, lightswitch-2012

I am using sql server 2008. I attempted to use geography data type. But i'm using lightswitch 2012 and it doesnt' support geography so I have to change the data type for long/lat.
Whats the best practice in this case? decimal(9,6) ???

Answer (score 1):

Yes using **decimal(9,6)** would be the best approach in your case.

Actually, Latitude is still easy to deal with. It's about 69 miles per degree.

Longitude is a little more complex, since 1° of longitude = (69.11) x (cosine of the latitude).

You may check out the [Spatial data-types](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb933876%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) which are specially made for these purposes.

Comment: sigh I just explained why I can't use that

Comment: @Sirus:- I am so sorry that I skipped that. Anyways in that case using decimal(9,6) would be the best approach!

Comment: Why to use lat/long expressed as miles? Why not Km? or even better degrees and transform for localized measure system by demand?